# Trying to add text before an existing division

Tags: javascript, jquery, insert

I've been reading a ton of questions/answers here but just cannot figure out how to edit them to make it work for me.

I have a `<div id="privacy">` and I want to add some text before it. Following some examples here, I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var parent =document.getElementById('privacy')
  var text=document.createTextNode('<div id="tollfree" style="left:750px;position:absolute;top:7px;font-size:18px;line-height:14px;"><strong>US Toll FREE: 1-888-555-1212<br><span style="font-size:12px;"> Promo Code "NAME"</span></strong></div>');
parent.insertBefore(text, parent);
</script>
```

but nothing shows up. I really know nothing about javascript or jquery so am not sure what I am supposed to put where, like am i supposed to put the code I want to add after the createTextNode? So confused. How can it get this to do it?

Comment: What made you think you could just stick a HTML string inside a method that creates a textNode and get something back ?

Comment: where in your page do you trigger this javascript? Because you have to make sure that you either put the script tag at the bottom of the page. Or you use a check to see if the document is loaded. Otherwise it could be that the code is triggered before the privacy-div was initialized. Also use the "createElement" function to create html elements

Comment: You already have an answer, but the proper way to do this with javascript would be to build the markup and then join it together and insert it, like [**this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x5qBC/)

Answer (score 3):

With jQuery you can do the following

```
var $node = $('<div id="tollfree" style="left:750px;position:absolute;top:7px;font-size:18px;line-height:14px;"><strong>US Toll FREE: 1-888-555-1212<br><span style="font-size:12px;"> Promo Code "NAME"</span></strong></div>');
$node.insertBefore($('#privacy'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you've *tagged* jQuery, I assume you are using it, in which case you can do:

```
$('<your-html/>').insertBefore('#privacy');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use different approach then [createTextNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTextNode). Because it creates only text node.

Answer (score 1):

[Here the full documentation](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) about `insertBefore` function.

```
<div id="privacy">
 ...
</div>
```

Use `jQuery` function:

```
$('your_selector').insertBefore('#privacy');
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I had a feeling I was making it overly complicated since all the examples I was finding were for much more complex things then just adding text!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      #tollfree{ 
        left:750px;
        position:absolute;
        top:7px;
        font-size:18px;
        line-height:14px; 
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="privacy">This is pivate</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var parent =document.getElementById('privacy'),
          textDiv = document.createElement('div');

      textDiv.innerHTML = '<strong>US Toll FREE: 1-888-555-1212<br><span style="font-size:12px;"> Promo Code "NAME"</span></strong>'
      textDiv.setAttribute('id', 'tollfree');
      parent.insertBefore(textDiv, parent.firstChild);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You should also try and avoid inline CSS (as I have done with div#tollfree) and if you have to do this more than once or twice, consider using a template instead.

Answer (score 1):

The way `insertBefore` works is that you need to call it on the container element, but also pass it a reference element to insert before, which would be your `div` with the `id` "privacy".  I used `innerHTML` to append the desired markup for this new `div` you are inserting.

```
var parent = document.getElementById('container');
var reference = document.getElementById('privacy');
var text = document.createElement('div');

text.id = 'tollfree';
parent.insertBefore(text, reference);
document.getElementById('tollfree').innerHTML = '<strong>US Toll FREE: 1-888-555-1212<br><span> Promo Code "NAME"</span></strong>';
```

Also, I would separate your css styling for this new `div` from the markup:

```
#tollfree {
    left:750px;
    position:absolute;
    top:7px;
    font-size:18px;
    line-height:14px;
}

#tollfree span {
    font-size:12px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5fKwg/